# Getting garbage inside my string

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, garbage

I'm writing a program which takes two strings and inputs one string into the other so that:

- String 1: **abc**
- String 2: **123**
- Output: **a123b123c123**

Now for some reason my output string gets garbage in the middle: **a123=b123=c123**. I have no idea why and would love some help!

Here's the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define N 80
#define ONE 1
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void InputStr(char str[]);
char* CreateString(char str1[], char str2[]);
int main()
{
    char strA[N], strB[N], *strF;

    InputStr(strA);
    InputStr(strB);
    strF = CreateString(strA, strB);
    puts(strF);

}

void InputStr(char str[])
{

    printf("Please enter the string\n");
    scanf("%s", str);


}
char* CreateString(char str1[], char str2[])
{

    char* newstr;
    int len1, len2, size, i, j, b;
    len1 = strlen(str1);
    len2 = strlen(str2);
    size = len1*len2;
    newstr = (char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char) + 1);
    for (i = 0, b = 0; i<len1; i++, b++)
    {
        newstr[b] = str1[i];
        b++;
        for (j = 0; j<len2; j++, b++)
            newstr[b] = str2[j];


    }
    newstr[b + ONE] = 0;
    printf("test\n");
    return newstr;


}
```

Comment: Are you sure `size = len1*len2;`?? Wouldn't `+` be sufficient?

Comment: No need for casting the results of `malloc`. Know the difference between a NULL vs NUL.

Comment: @t0mm13b, Oh yes it is, it gets a pointer to storage area and fills that storage area.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Woops..

Comment: You also have a problem with your `malloc()`, the `+ 1` is misplace! Here is what you should have: `newstr = (char*)malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Your problem

You are incrementing your `b` variable 2 times:

```
for (i = 0, b = 0; i < len1; i++, b++) // First increment
{
    newstr[b] = str1[i];
    b++; // Second increment
    for (j = 0; j < len2; j++, b++)
        newstr[b] = str2[j];
}
```

### Solution

Just remove the first `b` increment and you code will work:

```
for (i = 0, b = 0; i < len1; i++) // No more b increment
{
    newstr[b] = str1[i];
    ++b; // You only need this increment
    for (j = 0; j < len2; j++, b++)
        newstr[b] = str2[j];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are increasing `b` every time.(that too twice) Just do it when you need it. Otherwise there are holes in the string.

```
for (i = 0, b = 0; i<len1; i++)
{
    newstr[b++] = str1[i];
    for (j = 0; j<len2; j++)
        newstr[b++] = str2[j];    
}
```

Then a small change would be

```
newstr[b] = 0;
```

After the end of the loop.

Also don't cast the return value of malloc. Check the return value of `malloc` for a `NULL` check and handle it approprioately.

Also when multiplying check if there is any overflow or not. In case of overflow handle it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem, my for loop did one more b++ and it made an empty cell in my string.

Comment: See how usefull a debugger would be? on your first attempt with stepping through the code with the debugger, you would have found the problem; no need to ask Stack Overflow...:-)